# How design and implement a service on SOA?

Tags: design-patterns, service, soa

I'm working to design an application having a core project that use different other projects that i want to expose as services. 
Example : Application A  use Service S1
External Application B , use Service S1

I want to make services easily adaptable for different use.  So I can use the service internally without using web services call , or decide to expose easily this service for an external use ( as a web service or Message style ..) . There is any design pattern that can help to do this ?

Comment: Just follow good OO design practices to keep your code flexible and you will be able to expose services when the need arises. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29 When you do, read this first. http://www.drdobbs.com/errant-architectures/184414966

Comment: Read more about "Microservices" architecture here: http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html